# How to submit a request for some given condition using jscript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried this code:

```
while (true) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                if ($("h2").text() == "Qu’est-ce qu’une année-lumière ?") {
                    $("#choice2").delay(200).queue(function () {
                        $(this).click().dequeue()
                    })
                }
            }, 10000)
        }
```

. My aim is actually to send an answer as the page DOM is already ready if the element in the tag  is verified, then i want to repeat this for as i am on that page. I tried many codes but my browser doesn't like them: it freezes... that is why i try to use an interval, but i am unable to control it yet. please i need your help...

Comment: Please format your question and your code. It is unreadable. Of course your browser freezes, you deliberately wrote an infinite loop (while true).

Answer (score 0):

The browser freezes because you have an infinite loop. It will just keep binding more and more `ready` events until the code is stopped for taking too long to run, or when the browser crashes because you have bound a zillion event handlers.

Adding the interval was the right move to make the code run more than once, but the `while` loop still kept it from working.

Remove the `while` loop, and your code will run. You don't need to dequeue a function that you queued, it will be dequeued when it runs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    if ($("h2").text() == "Qu’est-ce qu’une année-lumière ?") {
      $("#choice2").delay(200).queue(function () {
        $(this).click();
      });
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```

The interval runs the code every 10 seconds, so there doesn't seem to be any reason to wait for 200 ms before invoking the click, though.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, i would like to the ask what about this code:
           $(document).ready(function() {
                if ($("h2").text() == "Qu’est-ce qu’une année-lumière ?") {
                    $("#choice2#).click();
                }
                      else { }
                      
                   }, 5000)
            };
             location.reload(true);

Comment: @franckstifler: There is no interval parameter for the `ready` method. Making a reload immediately when the page is parsed would mean that the browser would just keep reloading the page indefinitely and never get to actually showing any of it.